# What will happen when fielder's body hits the wicket while doing the run out?

Tags: cricket

If the fielder has a ball in his hand and he is going for run out. Suppose his body  hits the wicket while doing the stumping not his hand then what will happen?

Answer (score -1):

It's a not out.The hand which holds the ball should remove the bail(s)from wickets.If the ball is only in one hand and the other hand which is not in contact with the ball removes the bail(s) then it's not out.if the ball is in fielder's hands and he removes the bail(s) with legs it's not out.if the body causes the stumps to fall while the ball is in hands it's not out.

Comment: Not true.  Any part of the body may remove the bails, as long as the ball is securely held, and the batsman is out.

Comment: The answer is correct, @Chenmunka. The bails or stumps must be removed by the hand holding the ball, or the arm of that hand.

Comment: It's out when the bails were removed by any part which holds the ball.How can it be out when ball is held in one part and the other part removes the bail(s).I answered according to the mentioned case in the question.upvote the answer if you like the comment.

Comment: Then the law has changed since the days when I umpired cricket.  It won't be the only law to have changed.